# Diophantine Equation Help

Tags: diophantine-equations

Exam question stumped me, can I have some help?

Find all the positive integer solutions of to:
$35=x^2-y^2$

Comment: $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$. So $(x+y)$ and $(x-y)$ are divisors of $35$. The divisors of $35$ are $1,5,7,35$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y) $$
$$35=1\times 35=5\times 7$$
thus
$$x+y=35 ; x-y=1$$
or
$$x+y=7 ; x-y=5$$
finally, the solutions set is
$$S=\{(18,17),(6,1)\} $$

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the $\,A$-function of [Eucid's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#:%7E:text=Euclid%27s%20formula%20for%20Pythagorean%20triples,t%20is%20a%20rational%20number.) $\,F(m,k)\,$
for generating Pythagorean triples, shown here as
$\,A=m^2-k^2.\quad$ We can find the $\,(m,k)\,$ values by solving for $\,k\,$ and testing a defined range of $\,m$-values to see which yield integers.
$$A=m^2-k^2\implies k=\sqrt{m^2-A}\quad\text{for}\quad  \sqrt{A+1} \le m \le \frac{A+1}{2}$$
The lower limit ensures $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and the upper limit ensures $m> k$.
$$A=35\implies \sqrt{35+1}=6\le m \le \frac{35+1}{2} =18\\ 
\text{and we find}\quad m\in\{6,18\}\implies k \in\{1,7\} $$
Using all three functions of Euclid's formula yields the following triples.
$$F(6,1)=(35,12,37)\qquad  F(18,17)=(35,612,613)\qquad  $$